# Как зациклить функцию, чтобы ее выполнение являлось гарантированным

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, исключения

Программа обращается к сети интернет для получения данных из списка исходных ID. Ночью интернет частенько отваливается, что приводит к ошибке программы.
Как добиться безаварийной работы программы, чтобы элемент списка был обработан гарантированно? Что нужно написать после `except:`, чтобы программа повторно обращалась к блоку `try:`, покуда его не обработает с корректным получением результата `y`.

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def Scan_data(x):
    try:
        y = <..Обращение к интернету..>
    except:
        time.timesleep(60)
        # <..Тут не знаю что написать..>
    return y

for i in data:
    Scan_data(i)
```

Comment: может бесконечный цикл _перед_ `try`?

Comment: каждый `x` должен быть успешно обработан единоразово. в бесконечном цикле функция будет получать один и тот же результат постоянно

Comment: дополнительно `break` _перед_ `except` ?

Comment: точно. спасибо. размести в ответах выберу как решение

Comment: у @KoVadim такое же решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот где то так. Я также добавил счетчик неуспешних попыток. Если было больше 1000 попыток, то не ведомо, если ли смысл продолжать.

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def Scan_data(x):
    y = -1
    happy = false
    tr = 0 # сколько раз пробовали
    while (!happy and tr < 1000):
        try:
            y = <..Обращение к интернету..>

            happy = true # как только поняли, что все ок
        except:
            time.timesleep(60)
            tr = tr + 1 # кол-во попыток
            print("попытка номер ", tr)
    return y

for i in data:
    Scan_data(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал так

```
def Scan_data(x):
   try:
      y = ...
      return y
   except:
      return None

for i in data:
    while Scan_data(i) is None:
       time.timesleep(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Примените рекурсию:

`def Scan_data(x):
        try:
            y = <..Обращение к интернету..>
        except:
            time.timesleep(60)
            Scan_data(x)
        return y`

Comment: У когда есть проблема. Если кол-во "обращений" будет больше 1000, то оно упадет.